# Stop code execution Java

Tags: java

So I've been building a program that basically calls out to my server and checks the page source code. The only problem is that since I have an infinite loop, So it gets the source code of the server and then at the bottom of the loop it saves the current page code and refreshes the actual page code in a different variable. If theses 2 variables match (Nothing has changed) Then it's going to keep looping through and calling the page and getting the source code over and over again. This works great except that after a while the server thinks it is a DoS attack and won't let me connect. I've tried making a method where it would be a super long loop, but that seems like a messy way of doing it. My question, is their anyway to tell Java to just completely stop code execution for a set amount of time. So for example it will call the server every 1 or 2 minutes?

```
package Mailer2;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.Message.RecipientType;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;
public class mailer2 {
    static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) throws AddressException, MessagingException, IOException, InterruptedException{
        System.out.println("Admin console");
        boolean StartServer = true;
        String old = "";

        while(StartServer == true){
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        // Get Info from Page
        String From = "";
        String To = "";
        String Subject = "";
        String Body = "";
        String Provider = "";
        URL GetInfo = new URL("http://smsmessenger.comuf.com/Users.php");

        String GetPage = getPageCode(GetInfo);
        //System.out.println("Got the String:" + GetPage);
        String CutDown = GetPage.substring(73,GetPage.indexOf("<br"));
        //System.out.println(CutDown);
        From = CutDown.substring(0,CutDown.indexOf("TO:")); // From
        //System.out.println(From);
        To = CutDown.substring(CutDown.indexOf("TO:") + 3,CutDown.indexOf("SUBJECT") - 1);
        //System.out.println(To);
        Subject = CutDown.substring(CutDown.indexOf("SUBJECT:") + 8,CutDown.indexOf("BODY"));
        //System.out.println(Subject);
        Body = CutDown.substring(CutDown.indexOf("BODY:") + 5, CutDown.indexOf("Provider"));
        //System.out.println(Body);
        Provider = CutDown.substring(CutDown.indexOf("Provider:") + 9);
        //System.out.println(Provider);

        // Cell provider check
        if(Provider.length() == 0){
            System.out.println("No Provider Detected!");
        }
        else if(Provider.toLowerCase().equals("sprint")){
            To += "@messaging.sprintpcs.com";
            //System.out.println("Sprint HERE:" + To);
        }
        else if(Provider.toLowerCase().equals("verizon")){
            To += "@vtext.com";
        }
        else if(Provider.toLowerCase().equals("att")){
            To += "@txt.att.net";
        }
        else if(Provider.toLowerCase().equals("tmobile") || Provider.toLowerCase().equals("t-mobile")){
            To += "@tmomail.net";
        }
        else{
        System.out.println("Provider NOT FOUND" + Provider);
        }
        if(!old.equals(GetPage)){
            System.out.println("SENDING EMAIL!!");
        SendEmail(From,To,Subject,Body);
        }
        System.out.println("Sleeping");
        Thread.sleep(100);
         old = GetPage;

        }


    }

    public static void SendEmail(String From, String To, String Subject, String Body) throws AddressException, MessagingException{

        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.put("mail.smtp.host", "ssrs.reachmail.net");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");


        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(prop, new Authenticator() {

            // Override method to Authenticate to mail server
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication("MCA28\\admin", "pass");
            }
            });

        session.setDebug(true);

        MimeMessage Msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        //System.out.println("Please enter the From:");
        //String setFrom = console.nextLine();
        Msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(From));
        //System.out.println("Please enter which email to send to");
        //String setTo = console.nextLine();
        Msg.setRecipients(RecipientType.TO, To);
        //System.out.println("Set the Subject");
        //String subject = console.nextLine();
        Msg.setSubject(Subject);
        //System.out.println("Set the message Body");
        //String MessageBody = console.nextLine();
        // Initiate MimeBodyPart for filling email content
        MimeBodyPart messagePart = new MimeBodyPart();
        messagePart.setText(Body);
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        multipart.addBodyPart(messagePart);
        Msg.setContent(multipart);

        // Email Sending process
        Transport.send(Msg);

    }
    public static String getPageCode(URL SQL) throws IOException // Gets URL, returns InputLine
    {
        URLConnection openLine = SQL.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = null;
        String inputLine = null;
        String line;
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(openLine.getInputStream()));

        while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
        {
            inputLine += line;
        }

        return inputLine;

    }


}
```

Comment: Use a Timer, perhaps?

Comment: Uh, your code already has `Thread.sleep(10000);` and `Thread.sleep(100);` in it. What do you think these do?

Comment: Yea got it, i just increased the Thread.sleep time to 1 minute. I've been coding this server & Program for the last 12+ hours so i guess my brain turned off somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no changes, double the time until the next requery. Keep doubling until some preset maximum is reached, say an hour between polls. As soon as you detect changes, you can return to querying more often.